# VB.net Read Specific Lines From a Text File That Start With and Stop Reading When Start With

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, text-files, file.readalllines

I'm looking to read lines from a text file that start with certain characters and stop when the line starts with other characters.  So in my example I would like to start reading at line AB and stop at line EF however not all lines will contain the CD line.  There will always be a AB line and EF line, however the number of lines in between is unknown.

Here is an example of the lines in a text file I would be reading.  You can see that this will create two rows in the DataGridView however the first row is missing the CD line and should be blank.

```
AB-id1
EF-address1
AB-id2
CD-name1
EF-address2
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(textfile)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            If lines(i).StartsWith("AB") Then
            Dim nextLines As String() = lines.Skip(i + 1).ToArray
            
            Dim info As String = nextLines.FirstOrDefault(Function(Line) Line.StartsWith("CD"))
            Dim name As String = "Yes"
            
            Dim info2 As String = nextLines.FirstOrDefault(Function(Line) Line.StartsWith("EF"))
            Dim address As String = "Yes"
            End If

            DataGridView.Rows.Add(name,address)
    Next
```

Now the output I currently get is:

```
|Yes|Yes|
|Yes|Yes|
```

And I should be getting:

```
||Yes|
|Yes|Yes|
```

It looks like it's reading too far down the text file and I need it to stop reading at EF.  I've tried Do while and Do Until with no success.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Array.FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=net-5.0#System_Array_FindIndex__1___0___System_Int32_System_Predicate___0__) function to get the index of the next line starting with your prefix.  This way you don't have to skip lines and create a new array each time.

Try this out instead:

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(textFile)
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    If lines(i).StartsWith("AB") Then
        Dim addressIndex As Integer = Array.FindIndex(lines, i + 1, Function(Line) Line.StartsWith("EF"))
        Dim address As String = If(addressIndex <> -1, lines(addressIndex).Substring(3), "") ' Get everything past the "-"

        Dim name As String = ""
        If addressIndex <> -1 Then
            Dim nameIndex As Integer = Array.FindIndex(lines, i + 1, addressIndex - i, Function(line) line.StartsWith("CD"))
            If nameIndex <> -1 Then
                name = lines(nameIndex).Substring(3) ' Get everything past the "-"
            End If
        End If

        DataGridView.Rows.Add(name, address)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I still have the same issue.  If the line CD doesn't exist it just copies the data from the first CD it sees.  If you use my example data with this name1 will appear twice.

Comment: Ah...so we need to search for the "EF" first, then use the overload that lets you give start/stop to search for the "CD" afterwards.  Will update the code.

Comment: Yes, basically I want to start searching at each line that starts with AB and stop at line EF.